# Regex to check for everything except a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regex to match everything but the string containing "domain.com/file/".

So if I am given a url I want to make sure that it does not contain "domain.com/file/".

I know this is probably super easy but I am a noob at regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

**You can use [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) for this instead of regular expressions.**  It's poorly named, but it will return `false` if it fails to find the string.  Be sure to use `===` instead of `==` as strings will have truthy values.

You don't really need the power of regular expressions unless your question was not specific enough.

**After reviewing a few things, it seems that [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is actually faster than `strstr`.**  You definitely need to use to use `===` instead of `==` with this function.

*Example of `strpos` from the php docs:*

```
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

Comment: This is a better way to go because it is less expensive than a regex.

Comment: Should probably use stristr instead of strstr to make it more secure.

Comment: When using `strstr` you can leave the boolean evaluation to PHPs boolean interpretation logic. The `===` workaround is important for `strpos` only.

Comment: @mario It returns the string BEFORE your string.  If the string was "0domain.com/file/" you'd get false, but really it is true.  Contrived example, I know.  But worth noting, I think.

Comment: It only does that if the last parameter is set to true. The default is using the needle as start anchor and returning everything from there. So the booleaness of the needle is sufficient.

Comment: @mario It doesn't seem to be documented well, but honestly, `strpos` is the better function for this.

Answer (score 1):

An example using case-insensitive match:

```
if (stristr($input, 'domain.com/file/') === false) {
   // not found.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use ! as the NOT operator in Regex

```
$pattern = '#!domain\.com/file/#';
if(preg_match($pattern,$data)){

}
```

Comment: This works in a `.htaccess` RewriteRule, but `!` alone has no significance in a regex.

Answer (score 0):

To also answer the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) question: You could use a [`(?!...)` negative assertion](http://www.google.com/search?q=regex+lookaround) for that purpose:

```
if (preg_match("~(?!.*domain.com/file/)~", $string))
```

This makes sense if you combine it with other comparisons. All by itself negating the [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) result would be more sensible.